# Magento 2 URL Rewrites

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, magento2

I have recently moved my store over to Magento 2. The store is up and running and all is good. I've just noticed that for most products, Magento 2 has created 3 different URL's for the same product.

If for instance, the product is located in Category A > Sub Category B. The following URL's are created;

```
mystore.com/product.html,
mystore.com/categorya/product.html,
mystore.com/categorya/subcategoryb/product.html
```

I think this will end up being a problem for search engines, as its going to result in a fair bit of duplicate content.

Ideally I'd like to just keep the;

```
mystore.com/categorya/subcategoryb/product.html
```

url, how can I stop Magento from rewriting the other 2 urls, whilst making sure links still work from all pages.

It's worth mentioning, that if I visit the product from a home page link, it uses the mystore.com/product.html url. Whilst if I visit the product from the Category A page, it uses the mystore.com/categorya/product.html url. Similar if I click a link in the subcategory.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to remove the category paths as this give Google more information to rank your products more highly. Setting the `<link  rel="canonical" href="mystore.com/product.html" />` on your product page might be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use default magento settings by stores->configuration -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> 'yes'

If this can solve your problem